# How to Make Album view of An Images which coming from web service in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gallery

I am working on gallery module in which the URL of images coming from web API.In the API there is an event name,image url and description of event.now i want an Album view of particular event.i want to make album of particular event with by default first image and clicking on that album display another images of event.

I want view like this which displayed in image.there is an photo album of particular event and by clicking on that photo album another images of that events are shown.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td6T0.jpg)

This is My Json Response.

```
[
  {
    "Rownumber": 1,
    "id": 251,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/1635242229_1998256693552243_3617232473282314240_n.jpg",
    "Name": "DAMPATI SHIBIR",
    "Description": "VIVAHIK JIVAN",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-07-02T01:17:23.773",
    "CreatedBy": "HIMANSHU_ADMIN",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  },
  {
    "Rownumber": 2,
    "id": 252,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/1635272131_1998256603552252_3478881719728209920_n.jpg",
    "Name": "DAMPATI SHIBIR",
    "Description": "VIVAHIK JIVAN",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-07-02T01:17:23.773",
    "CreatedBy": "HIMANSHU_ADMIN",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  },
  {
    "Rownumber": 3,
    "id": 253,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/16WhatsAppImage2018-06-13at11.21.20AM.jpeg",
    "Name": "DAMPATI SHIBIR",
    "Description": "VIVAHIK JIVAN",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-07-02T01:17:23.79",
    "CreatedBy": "HIMANSHU_ADMIN",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  },
  {
    "Rownumber": 4,
    "id": 247,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/",
    "Name": "MAHAVIR",
    "Description": "",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-01-27T15:19:49.553",
    "CreatedBy": "Bhavesh",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  },
  {
    "Rownumber": 5,
    "id": 248,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/1510991329_460478337432578_9007253566282945229_n.jpg",
    "Name": "MAHAVIR",
    "Description": "",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-01-27T15:20:03.367",
    "CreatedBy": "Bhavesh",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  },
  {
    "Rownumber": 6,
    "id": 249,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/15290643_118745158223390_7028747_o.jpg",
    "Name": "MAHAVIR",
    "Description": "",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-01-27T15:20:26.183",
    "CreatedBy": "Bhavesh",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  },
  {
    "Rownumber": 7,
    "id": 250,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/14304977_314992211932016_2142854253_n.jpg",
    "Name": "MAHAVIR SANKARDHAM 2016",
    "Description": "",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-01-27T02:57:12.157",
    "CreatedBy": "Bhavesh",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  },
  {
    "Rownumber": 8,
    "id": 244,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/14295597_118745108223395_4830375_n.jpg",
    "Name": "MAHAVIR SANKARDHAM 2016",
    "Description": "",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-01-27T00:00:00",
    "CreatedBy": "Bhavesh",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  },
  {
    "Rownumber": 9,
    "id": 245,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/1410372160_410043112476101_1188375874765955878_n.jpg",
    "Name": "MAHAVIR SANKARDHAM 2016",
    "Description": "",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-01-27T15:14:12.17",
    "CreatedBy": "Bhavesh",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  },
  {
    "Rownumber": 10,
    "id": 246,
    "image_url": "~/gallery/14304977_314992211932016_2142854253_n.jpg",
    "Name": "MAHAVIR SANKARDHAM 2016",
    "Description": "",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-01-27T15:14:42.58",
    "CreatedBy": "Bhavesh",
    "TotalRecords": 10
  }
]
```

i want to display images in a particualr album which is having same name.

Comment: can you provide some screenshot for more clarity, In my opinion, you can add some header view date wise in react native

Comment: @RajshekharYadav i have edited my post.can you please give me some advise on this.thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I have  some clarification on,  You want to show album name from `Name `, `image_url ` use this as  cover image ? I am sure u must be using the recyclerView for this.

Comment: @RajshekharYadav I want to show album view of the  images which having same name.in API there is an URL of images and name.suppose name is MAHAVIR so all Mahavir event images in one album and another event ..images in another album ... In my. Code I used recycler view and call API using volly and showing image using picasso.it shows all the images in gridview but I want album wise view

Answer (score 0):

Steps :-

1. Parse the JSON response to a model
2. Bind the model to recyclerview
3. Add GLide library to handle images from Image URL.

Attached a tutorial:-

[Gallery](https://javapapers.com/android/android-image-gallery-example-app-using-glide-library/)

Comment: hey Nidhin Prathap. thanks but i have already done this using picasso library.its giving me gallery view of all the images in API.i want to make an album view of particular group of images.i posted the screenshot which i want as a view in my application.

Answer (score 0):

First Creat a Data Class:

```
   data class  AlbumInfo(var Rownumber:Int,
                      var id:Int,
                      var image_url :String,
                      var Name :String,
                      var Description :String,
                      var CreatedDate :String,
                      var TotalRecords :String

)
```

Then the other Data Class for Album

```
  data class  AlbumName(var albumName:String, var url :String,var list:List<AlbumInfo>)
```

Then just do the `groupBy()` and you will get the required structure
I did on the Basis of `Name`

```
 var result=  list.groupBy {  it.Name}.entries.map { (name, group) ->
          AlbumName(name, group[0].image_url,group)
      }
```

I guess that will help you. Use the `result` for your recyclerview.
You will get a response like this.

```
[
  AlbumName(albumName=DAMPATISHIBIR,
  url=~/gallery/1635242229_1998256693552243_3617232473282314240_n.jpg,
  list=[
    AlbumInfo(Rownumber=1,
    id=1,
    image_url=~/gallery/1635242229_1998256693552243_3617232473282314240_n.jpg,
    Name=DAMPATISHIBIR,
    Description=VIVAHIKJIVAN,
    CreatedDate=2018-07-02T01: 17: 23.773,
    TotalRecords=20),
    AlbumInfo(Rownumber=2,
    id=252,
    image_url=~/gallery/1635272131_1998256603552252_3478881719728209920_n.jpg,
    Name=DAMPATISHIBIR,
    Description=VIVAHIKJIVAN,
    CreatedDate=2018-07-02T01: 17: 23.773,
    TotalRecords=22)
  ]),
  AlbumName(albumName=MAHAVIR,
  url=~/gallery/1635272131_1998256603552252_3478881719728209920_n.jpg,
  list=[
    AlbumInfo(Rownumber=3,
    id=252,
    image_url=~/gallery/1635272131_1998256603552252_3478881719728209920_n.jpg,
    Name=MAHAVIR,
    Description=VIVAHIKJIVAN,
    CreatedDate=2018-07-02T01: 17: 23.773,
    TotalRecords=22),
    AlbumInfo(Rownumber=4,
    id=252,
    image_url=~/gallery/1635272131_1998256603552252_3478881719728209920_n.jpg,
    Name=MAHAVIR,
    Description=VIVAHIKJIVAN,
    CreatedDate=2018-07-02T01: 17: 23.773,
    TotalRecords=22)
  ]),
  AlbumName(albumName=MAHAVIRSANKARDHAM2016,
  url=~/gallery/1635272131_1998256603552252_3478881719728209920_n.jpg,
  list=[
    AlbumInfo(Rownumber=2,
    id=252,
    image_url=~/gallery/1635272131_1998256603552252_3478881719728209920_n.jpg,
    Name=MAHAVIRSANKARDHAM2016,
    Description=VIVAHIKJIVAN,
    CreatedDate=2018-07-02T01: 17: 23.773,
    TotalRecords=22)
  ])
]
```

Comment: hey thanks for the Answer. I posted my JSON response. I got some idea from your Answer,but my problem is that how can i set album view for particular event.how can i set album for event and set default image of album.

Comment: I added few changes plz look into it. I hope that will help u.

Comment: can you tell me where i have to place that group by query??

Comment: In ur api call where u r getting the response .. i guess currently u r getting the list without album  group by help u to make a filter